# Get value of Custom Taxonomy from Custom Post type

Tags: php, foreach, yoast

I am using two loops on a page, one is grouped posts using 'for each' and one is not.

They both use the same facetwp query which is:

```
<?php
return [
  "post_type" => [
    "prime-ministers"
  ],
  "post_status" => [
    "publish"
  ],
  "meta_query" => [
    "sort_0" => [
      "key" => "pm_century",
      "type" => "CHAR"
    ],
    "sort_1" => [
      "key" => "serving_period_1_start",
      "type" => "CHAR"
    ]
  ],
  "orderby" => [
    "sort_0" => "DESC",
    "sort_1" => "DESC"
  ],
  "posts_per_page" => -1
];
```

It's a custom post type called prime-ministers and I am trying to display the value of a custom taxonomy called 'party' - but I only want to show the Yoast Primary category

For some reason, it shows no problem in the regular ungrouped loop like so:

```
<?php $post_type = get_post_type();
        $id        = get_the_ID();
        $taxonomy  = current( get_object_taxonomies( $post_type, 'objects' ) )->name ?? false;
                                            
        $primary_term_id = function_exists( 'tsf' ) ? tsf()->get_primary_term( $id, $taxonomy ) : 0;
        $primary_term_id = $primary_term_id ?: ( get_the_terms( $id, $taxonomy )[0]->term_id ?? null );
                                            
        if ( $primary_term_id ) {
            $term = get_term( $primary_term_id, $taxonomy ); ?>
                                            
            <p class="main-listing-party"><?php echo $term->name ?? '';?> </p>
            
<?php } ?>
```

But it does not work (it displays nothing at all) in the 'for each' loop which is this:

```
<?php
    
        $century_posts = array();
    
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            $century = get_field('pm_century', get_the_id());
            $century_posts[$century][] = $post;
        }
    
        wp_reset_query();
    
        foreach ($century_posts as $century_post => $century_title) {
    ?>

<!-- Display the century -->

        <div class="century-line-wrap">

            <h2 class="century-name"><?php echo esc_html($century_post); ?></h2>
            <div class="century-line"></div>
            
        </div>
          
          
        <?php
            
          foreach ($century_title as $listing => $single_listing) {
            setup_postdata($single_listing);
            $post_id = $single_listing->ID;
            $title = get_the_title($post_id);
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ), 'large' ); 
        ?>

        
        <?php $nameclass = str_replace(" ", "", $title); ?>
        

              
        <div class="single-prime-minister <?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post_id, 'party', ' ',', ')); ?> <?php echo $nameclass ?>">
                                    
                <a href="<?php the_permalink($post_id); ?>" title="<?php echo $title ?>" aria-label="Find out more about <?php echo $title ?>"> 

                    <div class="pm-filter-profile-image">
                                               
                        <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="" />
                                       
                    </div>
                                        
                </a>

                                   
                <div class="pm-filter-details-wrap">
                    <h4><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h4> 
    
                        <?php $post_type = get_post_type();
                        $id        = get_the_ID();
                        $taxonomy  = current( get_object_taxonomies( $post_type, 'objects' ) )->name ?? false;
                                            
                        $primary_term_id = function_exists( 'tsf' ) ? tsf()->get_primary_term( $id, $taxonomy ) : 0;
                        $primary_term_id = $primary_term_id ?: ( get_the_terms( $id, $taxonomy )[0]->term_id ?? null );
                                            
                        if ( $primary_term_id ) {
                        $term = get_term( $primary_term_id, $taxonomy ); ?>
                                            
                            <p class="main-listing-party"><?php echo $term->name ?? '';?> </p>
                        
                        <?php } ?>
    
    
                </div>

        </div>
              
        <?php
        }
          wp_reset_postdata();
          
        } ?>
```

I also tried this:

```
<?php
    $primary_term_id = yoast_get_primary_term_id( $post_id, 'party' );

?>

<p><?php echo $primary_term_id ?></p>
```

And

```
<?php $post_type = get_post_type();
        $taxonomy  = current( get_object_taxonomies( $post_type, 'objects' ) )->name ?? false;
                                            
        $primary_term_id = function_exists( 'tsf' ) ? tsf()->get_primary_term( $post_id, $taxonomy ) : 0;
        $primary_term_id = $primary_term_id ?: ( get_the_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy )[0]->term_id ?? null );
                                            
        if ( $primary_term_id ) {
            $term = get_term( $primary_term_id, $taxonomy ); ?>
                                            
            <p class="main-listing-party"><?php echo $term->name ?? '';?> </p>
            
<?php } ?>
```

Nothing I do seems to work

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I got this working with

```
<?php $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
      $taxonomy  = current( get_object_taxonomies( $post_type, 'objects' ) )->name ?? false;
      $primary_term_id = function_exists( 'tsf' ) ? tsf()->get_primary_term( $id, $taxonomy ) : 0;
      $primary_term_id = $primary_term_id ?: ( get_the_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy )[0]->term_id ?? null );
                                            
      if ( $primary_term_id ) {
      $term = get_term( $primary_term_id, $taxonomy ); ?>
                                            
        <p class="main-listing-party"><?php echo $term->name ?? '';?> </p>
        
<?php } ?>
```